# Git Bash on Windows Terminal App aliases not working?

Tags: windows, terminal, git-bash, windows-terminal

I downloaded the **Windows Terminal** app from the Microsoft Store and to use Git Bash I had to add this profile manually. So I added the *bash.exe* on *C:\Program Files\Git\bin*, so it doenst just open git bash in a new window. The problem is this *bash.exe* doesnt recognize any aliases I have created for git bash.

Does anyone have any Idea why this is happening?

I tried adding the alias to *C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.h* and to a *.bash_profile* file in my windows user folder. Neither of these are working with the *bash.exe* but it is working with the defult *git-bash.exe*.

Comment: I have the same issue - Would be very interested in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your aliases aren't created yet, you need to [create them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452976/git-bash-on-windows-terminal-app-aliases-not-working).

Once you have the aliases created, you can modify your configurations in the Windows Terminal app.

To do this, access the Git Bash profile configuration and edit the CommandLine option with the value `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i`.

[Configuration Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTqa6.png)